# JSON returned by Solr

Tags: json, curl, post, solr, solr-query-syntax

I'm using Solr in order to index my data.

Through the Solr's UI I added, in the Schema window, two fields: word, messageid

After I made the following query post:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" 'http://localhost:8983/solr/messenger/update.json/docs' --data-binary '{"word":"hello","messageid":"23523}'
```

I received the following JSON:

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 55
  }
}
```

When I'm going to the Query Window in the API and Execute a query without parameters I get the following JSON:

```
{
  {
    "responseHeader": {
      "status": 0,
      "QTime": 0,
      "params": {
        "q": "*:*",
        "indent": "on",
        "wt": "json",
        "_": "1488911768817"
      }
    },
    "response": {
      "numFound": 1,
      "start": 0,
      "docs": [
        {
          "id": "92db6722-d10d-447a-b5b1-13ad9b70b3e2",
          "_src_": "{\"word\":\"hello\",\"messageid\":\"23523\"}",
          "_version_": 1561232739042066432
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Shouldn't my JSON appear more like the following one?:

```
//More Code
"response": {
  "numFound": 1,
  "start": 0,
  "docs": [
    {
      "id": "92db6722-d10d-447a-b5b1-13ad9b70b3e2",
      "word": "hello",
      "messageid": "23523",
      "_version_": 1561232739042066432
    }
//More Code
```

In order to be able later on to filter using parameters through the following option?:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out you were using so-called 'custom JSON indexing' approach which is described [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Transforming+and+Indexing+Custom+JSON). You can tweak it as described in the wiki in order to extract desired fields. Here is excerpt for your reference:

> **split**: Defines the path at which to split the input JSON into multiple Solr documents and is required if you have multiple documents in a single JSON file. If the entire JSON makes a single solr document, the path must be “/”. It is possible to pass multiple split paths by separating them with a pipe (|) example : split=/|/foo|/foo/bar . If one path is a child of another, they automatically become a child document
>
> **f**: This is a multivalued mapping parameter. The format of the parameter is target-field-name:json-path. The json-path is required. The target-field-name is the Solr document field name, and is optional. If not specified, it is automatically derived from the input JSON.The default target field name is the fully qualified name of the field. Wildcards can be used here, see the section Wildcards below for more information.

But I would recommend using the standard approach of indexing documents which is old good `update` command from [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Index+Handlers#UploadingDatawithIndexHandlers-AddingaSingleJSONDocument). So it would look more like:

```
 curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/messenger/update?commit=true' --data-binary '{"word":"hello","messageid":"23523}' -H 'Content-type:application/json'
```